# How to send Apple Push Notifications by using apnotic gem?

Tags: ruby, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send Apple's push notification by following the instruction of `apnotic` gem.

https://github.com/ostinelli/apnotic

```rb
require 'apnotic'

connection = Apnotic::Connection.development(
  auth_method: :token,
  cert_path: "AuthKey_foobar.p8",
  key_id: "foobar",
  team_id: "abcd1234"
)

# create a notification for a specific device token
token = 'abcdef123456..'

notification       = Apnotic::Notification.new(token)
notification.topic = "bundle_id"
notification.alert = "Notification from Apnotic!"

# send notifications and get results
response = connection.push(notification)

puts response.status
puts response.body

connection.close
```

However, I got the response.

```
403
{"reason"=>"ExpiredProviderToken"}
```

I don't think the token is actually expired because I can send notifications by using the app and same IDs and tokens.

https://github.com/onmyway133/PushNotifications

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my virtual machine's clock. After adjusting the clock(by installing `ntp`), it worked.

```sh
$ sudo apt install ntp
$ sudo service ntp status
● ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-08-17 05:46:06 UTC; 7s ago
   :
$ ruby push.rb 
200
{":status"=>"200", "apns-id"=>"......"}
```